# Excel Data Cleanup or consolidate

Tags: python, excel, transpose, data-cleaning

I have a large excel data:

[image: Current Data Style]

For each value from column **Column1**, there are 5 data in column **Column 2**. I need to organize this way:

[image: as per here]

**Note**: For most of the data in column **Column 1**, there should be 5 values, but for some there may be less. So whenever there is less data, we can skip that cell or mark with something like `nil/0`.

I tried sorting the data and also tried with the following excel formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*5-5+COLUMN(A1))
```

It basically transposes each 5 row to a column, but since there are some data having less than 5 values in **Column 2**, data gets unusable.

Looking forward to some solution Either via excel or via some python script.
[Sample Data Can Be Found here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R8CcO-lQVKsD_sFczaPHynY-ASF1HVSOWJ_E8wWckHY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code. Its just a excel data which i have attached at the botom

Comment: How the link:  [Sample Data Can Be Found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R8CcO-lQVKsD_sFczaPHynY-ASF1HVSOWJ_E8wWckHY/edit?usp=sharing) relates to the the problem your problem? Please provide something similar to the sample screenshot you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to identify unique elements on **Column 1** (adding a filter condition to exclude empty cells) on cell `D2`:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A20, A2:A20<>""))
```

Then starting on `E2` the following formula:

```
=IF(D2="","", 
  TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$B$20, ($A$2:$A$20=$D2) * ($A$2:$A$20<>""))))
```

[image: sample excel file]

then expand down the formula in `E2`. It works regardless of the number of elements on **Column 1**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the whole problem outlined may be solved with Excel built-in [Pivot Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

Or, if python solution is required, [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) may be used.